# Is iTunes Search API Rate Limit per device or per app?

Tags: itunes, itunes-search-api, itunes-api

I want to implement iTunes Search API in my app for my users to search for contents on iTunes

https://affiliate.itunes.apple.com/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api/

My app has about 100,000 users. 
I understand that there's a Rate Limit of about 20 calls per minute. But is the Rate Limit per device, or per app?

If the Rate Limit is per device, then it should be ok. Any one of my users shouldn't be searching for more than 20 times per minute. But if the Rate Limit is per app, then all of my users' searches add up will largely exceed the Rate Limit, then I should look into Enterprise Partner Feed and build a server for my users' searches?

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: From what I can tell, it's a rate limit per device / IP address.  I doubt they will go as far as to interrogating the headers to figure out if the API requests are coming from the same app.  You could simply randomize your request headers and they wouldn't be able to tell.

Comment: Thanks dhallman, I'll try using it and see what happens. Will update if I have the result.

Comment: I realize this is question is 4 years old, but any update as to wether this is per device?

Comment: @RogyBear from my experience, I believe the limit is not per App. Never hit the rate limit yet. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the response, John!