# Publicly available iOS app_id to app_bundle map?

Tags: ios, app-store

Does Apple provide a flat file of app_id to app_bundle mappings for all app store apps, or do I need to query the iTunes lookup service for each app by app_id and then extract the app_bundle from the returned json file? This information is crucial for the advertising industry. Do Apple throttle requests to the lookup service?

Comment: Any suggestions to where this question could be moved?

Comment: What exactly are you talking about and what do you want to achieve? Do you mean the Apple ID (1234567...) with app_id of an app? Do you mean the bundle ID (com.apple.keynote) for the app_bundle? Please clarify or it will be hard to help you!

Comment: @oddie yes, that's what I mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the bundle ID is something every developer can choose on his own, there is no clear mapping. (Official) Public APIs for the App Store are really scarce, so your current "way" via the iTunes Lookup Service is the right one. There are a couple of threads on the limits:

> 20 calls / minute
>   [iTunes Search API rate limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12596300/itunes-search-api-rate-limit)
>
> 25-70 calls / minute
>   https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/66399