# Apple Music Search API rate limit

Tags: throttling, rate-limiting, apple-music

I'm using [Apple Music API](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/applemusicapi) to get track/album related information, [Search for catalog resources](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/applemusicapi/search_for_catalog_resources) Request.

I'd like to know if there is any rate limit on the API usage (request throttling). I couldn't find any details of this in their Documentation / Stack Overflow / Google. I did not get 429 status code (so far).

Is it the same limit as in iTunes Search API? (here's the [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12596300/1429387))

Does anyone have info on this?

---

#### Update

Request

```
curl -i 'https://api.music.apple.com/v1/catalog/ru/search?term=hi+so' -H "Authorization: Bearer ..."
```

response headers:
[image]

there's no "X-Rate-Limit" header.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently it varies but there's a header in the response "X-Rate-Limit" in the format "user-hour-lim:10;user-hour-rem:8;" that includes how many requests you can make an hour.

[Forum](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/110457)

[Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/applemusicapi/getting_keys_and_creating_tokens)

EDIT: Thanks @Satsuki for highlighting that some endpoints may not have a rate limit as described in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/applemusicapi/getting_keys_and_creating_tokens#3001403).

> If you are requesting anything from the Apple Music Catalog, the request will hit Apple's cache first, which doesn't check your rate limit.

Comment: actually, your link to the documentation is helpful!

Comment: Do you think this is a per user bases or a per token bases. Since this  can be a problem if number of users for a app rises.

Comment: @Satsuki It states in the forum link I provided that it's per key being used.

Comment: @Shoejep I was wondering if this is the case for catalog resources. In the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/applemusicapi/getting_keys_and_creating_tokens#3001403) it says
"If you are requesting anything from the Apple Music Catalog, the request will hit Apple's cache first, which doesn't check your rate limit. If you are requesting anything from a personalized endpoint, calling it will always check the rate limit."
Does this mean that accessing the Apple Music Catalog(like the question above) does not have a rate limit?

Comment: @Satsuki It's possible, it's difficult to say definitely without contacting Apple.

Comment: @Shoejep were you able to get an answer on this?

Comment: @Rohin12 You would need to contact Apple to confirm.

Comment: Where would I contact them. I got this message the last time I tried, "Here in Apple Developer Program Support, we provide administrative support to developers regarding App Store Connect, and the developer portal. We do not provide technical support for Apple APIs. "

Comment: @Rohin12 I don't know exactly, I don't do anything with Apple anymore. Perhaps you could try a forum post.

Comment: Hm yeah- no response since posting (week ago). Any other ideas? Thanks for help anyway!

Comment: @Rohin12 You could just start making requests, if under heavy loads you start getting rate limited then that endpoint is rate limited otherwise it's probably not.

Comment: Might do that although I don’t have developer program access and it’d be bad I think if I purchased it for the rate limit to be low and apply for all users the same